# emberjs assertion failed error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to insert data from ember's view  but am getting following error message:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key refunds but you have no mapping for it
```

and here is my coding can anyone correct it.

My handlebar

```
<form>
   <th>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="refund_amount" placeholder="Enter refund amount"}}</th>
   <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-success complete-btn" {{action saveRefund}}>Refund</button></td>
</form>
```

My js model

```
Office.Refund = DS.Model.extend({
    job_id: DS.attr('number'),
    customer_id: DS.attr('number'),
    amount: DS.attr('number')
});
```

MY js controller

```
saveRefund: function() {
    var refund = Office.Refund.createRecord({
    job_id: this.get('id'),
    customer_id: this.get('customer.id'),
    amount: this.get('refund_amount')
  });
    this.get('store').commit();
    refund.on('didCreate',function() {
    alert('created successfully');
  });
}
```

Here is my refund_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @refund = Thunderbolt::Refund.all
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @refund}
    end
  end
def new
    @refund = Refund.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @refund }
    end
  end

  def create
    refunds = params[:refund]
    @refund = Refund.new(job_id: refunds[:job_id], customer_id: refunds[:customer_id], amount: refunds[:amount])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @refund.save
        format.html { redirect_to @refund, notice: 'Refund successful.' }
        format.json { render json: @refund, status: :created, location: @refund }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @refund.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is my refund_serializer.rb

```
  class RefundSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :job_id, :customer_id, :amount, :created_at, :updated_at
  end
```

Here is my refund.rb model

```
  class Refund < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :id, :amount, :customer_id, :job_id, :created_at, :updated_at
  end
```

Comment: can you share the format of your JSON response, for the case of a single and multiple records?

Comment: Am getting alert as `created successfully` but actually not created. It is just empty. This is was am getting while seeing console  `{"refunds":[]}`

Comment: In firefox console url is `POST http://localhost:8080/refunds` and source is `{"refund":{"job_id":691,"customer_id":424,"amount":11}}`

Comment: I can see no `id` field in your response JSON, do you have a mapping to `job_id` or something defined for it?

Comment: This is a POST not response(`{"refund":{"job_id":691,"customer_id":424,"amount":11}}`) and my response is `{"refunds":[]}`

Comment: yeah I got this, but in the case of a new object creation your backend should return the newly created record (the same as in the POST) with an `id` field set, and it should be singular `refund` and not `refunds` this seams a lot like your rails refund_controller.rb is not returning the JSON as ember expects it

Answer (score 1):

Solved this error by adding `resources :refunds` in `routes.rb` instead of

```
  get "refunds/index"

  get "refunds/new"

  get "refunds/edit"

  get "refunds/show"
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the comments are getting to long I'll try to explain it in an answer. When you post a new record to be saved, your backend should return the new record with an `id` set to it like:

```
{
  "refund": {
    "id": 123,
    "job_id":691,
    "customer_id":424,
    "amount":1
  }
}
```

If `job_id` is your record's primary key the you need to have a mapping for it in your `DS.RESTAdapter`, do you?

Hope it helps.

Comment: job_id is not a primary key. And i dont have any mapping also.

Comment: @RelicSet, so my answer still applies, your JSON response is wrong and should have the format mentioned in the answer

Comment: Record is not saving thats why no reponse. But i cant find where i am wrong. can you help

Comment: @RelicSet, I'm sorry I'm not so much the rails expert :/