# Nested json object in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

The following link works till for positions but when i add another object(company) it is not displaying anything.

[Refer the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/357sg/5/)

```
App.jsonObject = {
    id: 1812,
    name: 'Brokerage Account',
    positions: [
        {
            symbol: 'AAPL',
            quantity: '300',
            company:[
                {
                    no: '1',
                    name: 'test'
                }
                ]
        },
        {
            symbol: 'GOOG',
            quantity: '500',
            company:[
                {
                    no: '2',
                    name: 'test123'
                }
                ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this is not working is because down your JSON structure you have plain javascript objects. For ember to be aware of changes and bindings to work you always need to use the framework's methods like `Ember.Object.create` (like you already do with App.account), `objectAt(0)`, `pushObject()` etc. to create your data structure. This way your bindings and everything else will then work as expected.

#### Edit in response to your last comment

A simplistic very straight forward way would be to change your code to this:

```
App.account = Ember.Object.create({
  id: 1812,
  name: 'Brokerage Account',
  positions: Ember.A([
    Ember.Object.create({
      symbol: 'AAPL',
      quantity: '300',
      company: Ember.A([
        Ember.Object.create({
          no: '1',
          name: 'test'
        })
      ])
    }),
    Ember.Object.create({
      symbol: 'GOOG',
      quantity: '500',
      company: Ember.A([
        Ember.Object.create({
          no: '2',
          name: 'test123'
        })
      ])
    })
  ])
});
```

So you can later use framework methods and do stuff like:

```
App.get('account').get('positions').pushObject(Ember.Object.create({symbol: 'MSFT', quantity: 200}));
```

or

```
App.get('account').get('positions').objectAt(0).setProperties({'quantity': 500});
```

and here your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WkGkj/3/

> Note, the fiddle is now working but please don't quote me on this approach since it's not the preferred ember way of building ember applications, I just made it work to backup my answer :) Also worth mentioning is that in your fiddle you are using 'ember 0.9.4`which is now very outdated since version`1.0.0-rc.6.1` is around.

Hope it helps.

Comment: please can you help in this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126663/emberjs-assertion-failed-error)

Comment: @RelicSet, let's finish one topic first :) is my answer working for you?

Comment: Already I am having a ember application with rails and it is large size application. So i need to complete most of my work in rails else browser will crash. This is working fine but i dont think this is good one.

Comment: @RelicSet, but it answers this question or not? if it does you should accept it first :)

Comment: can you help me in this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126663/emberjs-assertion-failed-error)